# Trying to decrypt a string using AES Managed

Tags: c#

I am trying to write code to decrypt a string.

I was given an equivalent in python and I am trying to create the same in . NET

Python:

```
//Initialization vector is just a string of 16 null bytes
iv = '\x00' * 16

//Create new AES object using the key and init vector
aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)

//Decrypt password and remove padding
result = aes.decrypt(myString).rstrip('\x0b\x08\x07')

return result
```

Here is my attempt:

```
byte[] iv = new byte[16];
byte[] rawPlaintext = Convert.FromBase64String("MyBase64String");
byte[] key = // Read from common source

using (Aes aes = new AesManaged())
            {
                aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
                aes.KeySize = 128;          // in bits
                aes.Key = new byte[128 / 8];  // 16 bytes for 128 bit encryption
                aes.IV = new byte[128 / 8];   // AES needs a 16-byte IV
                // Should set Key and IV here.  Good approach: derive them from 
                // a password via Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes 
                byte[] cipherText = key;
                byte[] plainText = iv;

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(rawPlaintext, 0, rawPlaintext.Length);
                    }

                    cipherText = ms.ToArray();
                }


                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length);
                    }

                    plainText = ms.ToArray();
                }
                string s = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(plainText);
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
```

It doesn't appear to be working for the result is a string of symbols.

Possible issues:

- I see a mode of CBC getting set.  I'm not sure where that equivalent setting would be.  I've tried to play with the PaddingMode.

- Could my iv byte[] be causing the issue?  Is the default null or 0?

EDIT:
- From what I am reading AesManaged uses AES in CBC mode so that should be a non-issue.

Comment: It would help if you provide sample input and expected sample output.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this:

```
string s = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(plainText);
```

to:

```
string s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainText);
```

Comment: @JDS "MyBase64String" - Please, send your sample.